# Find Parents Of Child in tree -Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this sample table (as tree for hierarchical SQL).

How could we find parents up to the root, based on child?

For example: find parents Of "Sally" - answer : Chris and Barbara Edsger and Barbara > Grandma

Sample data:

| FAMILY_MEMBER | MOTHER | FATHER | MARRIED_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Grandma | null | null | Grandpa |
| Grandpa | null | null | Grandma |
| Nana | null | null | Granddad |
| Granddad | null | null | Nana |
| Edsger | Grandma | Grandpa | Grace |
| Ada | Grandma | Grandpa | null |
| Grace | Nana | Granddad | Edsger |
| Alan | Nana | Granddad | null |
| Chris | Grace | Edsger | Elizabeth |
| Barbara | Grace | Edsger | null |
| Elizabeth | null | null | Chris |
| Tim | Elizabeth | Chris | null |
| Linus | Elizabeth | Chris | null |
| Sally | Elizabeth | Chris | null |

I wrote this query to find children of parent (and it works), but I could not write query to find parents based on a child.

```
SELECT lpad(' ',level*3,' ') || family_member as who, level
FROM family
start with family_member = 'Grandma'
Connect By Prior family_member IN (MOTHER, FATHER)
```

Comment: I cannot get the rule: why Barbara is a parent of Sally, but Elizabeth (which is declared as her mother) is not? Why Edsger is paired with Barbara also while there's only one Barbara in the tree, who was assigned at the previous step? Why Grace is also absent? Are parents in your model not the same parents that we used to call in real life?

Comment: @astentx Parents Of Sally Are (Elizabeth And Chris),  "Edsger" Have Two Childs: 1-Chris 2- Barbara and Because Barbara Not Married And Don't Have Children, So only One Time Repeated As The Child Of "Edsger" And Not Parent Of Any Row

Comment: *For example: find parents Of "Sally" - answer : Chris and **Barbara** Edsger and **Barbara** > Grandma*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reverse the condition:

```
SELECT lpad(' ',level*3,' ') || family_member as who,level
FROM family
START WITH family_member = 'Sally'
Connect By family_member IN (PRIOR mother, PRIOR father)
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE family (FAMILY_MEMBER, MOTHER, FATHER, MARRIED_TO) AS
SELECT 'Grandma',   null,       null,       'Grandpa' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Grandpa',   null,       null,       'Grandma' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Nana',      null,       null,       'Granddad' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Granddad',  null,       null,       'Nana' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Edsger',    'Grandma',  'Grandpa',  'Grace' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ada',       'Grandma',  'Grandpa',  null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Grace',     'Nana',     'Granddad',     'Edsger' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alan',      'Nana',     'Granddad',     null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Chris',     'Grace',    'Edsger',   'Elizabeth' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Barbara',   'Grace',    'Edsger',   null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Elizabeth',     null,       null,       'Chris' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tim',       'Elizabeth',    'Chris',    null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Linus',     'Elizabeth',    'Chris',    null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sally',     'Elizabeth',    'Chris',    null FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | WHO | LEVEL |
> | --- | --- |
> | `Sally` | 1 |
> | `Chris` | 2 |
> | `Edsger` | 3 |
> | `Grandma` | 4 |
> | `Grandpa` | 4 |
> | `Grace` | 3 |
> | `Nana` | 4 |
> | `Granddad` | 4 |
> | `Elizabeth` | 2 |

Answer (score 2):

You're finding `Grandma`, then looking down the tree. Try starting with `Sally` and looking up the tree.

```
select *
  from family
connect by family_member = prior mother or family_member = prior father
start with family_member = 'Sally'
```

Comment: The Query You Write Is Correct, But I Try This Two Separately For ** looking down**  `SELECT lpad(' ',level*3,' ') || family_member as who
FROM family
start with family_member = 'Grandma'
Connect By Prior family_member IN (MOTHER,FATHER)` And This One For **Looking UP** `SELECT lpad(' ',level*3,' ') || family_member as who,level
FROM family
START WITH family_member = 'Sally'
Connect By family_member IN (PRIOR mother, PRIOR father)`

Answer (score 1):

As The @MTO writes, The Final code Is Like This:

--This Query Shows The Tree **From Root** With Indentation

```
SELECT lpad(' ',level*3,' ') || family_member as who
FROM family
start with family_member = 'Grandma'
Connect By Prior family_member IN (MOTHER,FATHER)
```

--This Query Shows The Tree **From Child To Root** With Indentation

```
SELECT lpad(' ',level*3,' ') || family_member as who,level
FROM family
START WITH family_member = 'Sally'
Connect By family_member IN (PRIOR mother, PRIOR father)
```

--If You Want Work **More Dynamic** (with Row Num)

```
select lpad(' ',level*3,' ') || name as NAMEE from z_tree
start with id = 1
Connect By Prior ID  =parent_id
```